# Bad 3d triangle rendering

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to get the 3D triangle using opengl 3.1. It renders fine as 2D triangle but when I add third coordinate it doesn't do it like I want it. I add 0.0 z coodinate to all three triangle vertices. The following is the code:

```
void init( void )
{   
    vec3 points[NumPoints];

    /*
    points[0] = vec2(-0.9, 0.9 );
    points[1] = (vec2(-0.9, -0.9));
    points[2] = (vec2(0.9, -0.9));
   */

    points[0] = vec3(-0.9, 0.9, 0.0 );
    points[1] = vec3(-0.9, -0.9, 0.0 );
    points[2] = vec3(0.9, -0.9, 0.0 );


    // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader21.glsl", "fshader21.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); // white background
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
}


void display( void )
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumPoints );    // draw the points
    glFlush();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH );

    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    glutCreateWindow( "Triangle" );
    glewInit();
    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your post properly.

Comment: Where are you shaders? Also, you are not really adding anything new to the problem when you specify a 3rd component of **0.0** for all vertices, because when you specify 2D vertices they implicitly have a Z value of **0.0**. Likewise, when you specify 2D or 3D vertices, W is implicitly **1.0**. About all you are doing by adding this 3rd component is messing with the *stride* of your vertex array, which is specified incorrectly as MichaelIV points out in his answer... you either need to indicate that the vertex has 3 components instead of 2, or adjust the stride to be non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it adds zero to Z ,but that's what you are actually specifying in your vertex array. Also glVertexAttribPointer second param should be 3 in your case.